# Mechanism of ring expansion of epoxide

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, heterocyclic-compounds, ethers

The below transformation is from

> *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **1990**, 112, 14, 5583–5601

[image]

What does the treatment with lithium anion of ethoxyacetylene in the presence of the lewis acid do to epoxides? How does it lead to the compound **56**? Wouldn't the below be obtained after oxymercuration?
[image]

Comment: And what do you think?

Comment: Draw out the intermediate that is the product of step 1 then search "oxymercuration"

Comment: @Mithoron edited.

Comment: @Waylander but how does oxymercuration lead to the cyclisation?

Comment: Did you read the experimental section of the paper? After step 1 one has "crude *bis*-acetylenic alcohol."

Comment: Ignoring the OTBS and EtO groups, the product has 9 carbons, the same as the reactants (5 + 2 +2). Your product has only 6 carbons. Your enols tautomerizes to $\ce{-CO2Et}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BF3 facilitates the nucleophilic opening of epoxides by binding to the oxygen. Under its influence the lithium anion of ethoxyacetylene adds at the least hindered sites to both the epoxides opening them to secondary alcohols. The t-Butyldimethylsilylether is preserved.

In the second step Hg2+ adds to both ynol ether triple bonds to form a three-centred cationic mercurinium species (see [here](https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/Purdue/Purdue%3A_Chem_26605%3A_Organic_Chemistry_II_(Lipton)/Chapter_11.__Addition_to_pi_Systems/11.1%3A_Electrophilic_Addition/11.1.2_Electrophilic_Addition_to_Alkenes/11.1.2.3%3A_Oxymercuration) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rSnGm5NETo8) for the general mechanism). The mercurinium species are nucleophilically attacked by the secondary alcohols to give [5] rings. The C-Hg bonds cleave releasing Hg2+. The enol ethers hydrolyse to give the lactone carbonyl and you have your product.